# Capture a different authorised amount in Magento2 with Braintree

Tags: payment-gateway, magento2, braintree

I've integrated Braintree payment gateway in my Magento 2.2.2 food e-commerce site.
From current specifications, i need to authorise the amount when the order is placed, then capture a different (lower) amount that comes out after items weight check.

I have not found enough documentation to do that, and in Braintree site this topic seems to be not covered.

Any suggestion, documentation or code snipped will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Full disclosure: I currently work for Braintree. If you have any further questions, don't hesitate to contact [support](https://articles.braintreepayments.com/)</sub>

In Braintree you can just authorize a transaction by not passing the parameter `submit_for_settlement` to true as mentioned [here](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/transaction/sale/ruby#options.submit_for_settlement). If the transaction is not settled, you can submit that transaction for settlement later, and with a different amount, as long as the amount is not [more than the amount specified in the authorization](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/transaction/submit-for-settlement/ruby#arg.amount).